# Задать cookie для всего сайта

Tags: php, cookie

```
setCookie('hash', $user_hash, time() + 3600, '/');
```

В данном случае cookie не применяется в каталогах. Например в /test или /file.php

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде бы, Вы всё делаете правильно.  `Path` для куки равный корню сайта `'/'`, делает её видимой для любый подпапок. Может быть, стоит ещё явно указать домен следующим параметром, чтобы кука была доступна и для [site.ru](http://site.ru), и для [www.site.ru](http://www.site.ru)?

```
setCookie('hash', 'test me, please', time() + 3600, '/', 'site.ru');
```

Comment: @sergiks, да. Ваш вариант рабочий.

Comment: а как определить куку для всей папки например у меня /admin или для всего домена в localhost.