# Задать Laravel cookie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Как задать не сессионные куки в ларавел? То есть, что бы при первом соединение с сайтом, отдавать вечные куки, а не только сессионные. 
Попробовал задать через посредника куки сразу, они задаются, но их значения не шифруются и по итогу в реквесте их значение получить нельзя. Так что способа, кроме как через метод не нашел.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задать cookie для всего сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/151540/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-cookie-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано в официальных [доках](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies):

```
public function index()
{
    //first method
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('test1', 'value1', 10000000));

    //second method
    return response('Hello World')->cookie(
        'test2', 'value2', 10000000
    );
}
```

Либо использовать нативную для php функцию setCookie